# Where to find deb file for Blender 2.78c

Tags: installation, linux, versions

I've been using the [Blender PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender) which recently updated to 2.79.  However, I want to remain with 2.78c for a while, but I'm not sure how to get it from the PPA (or even if I can, or find a deb file.  We're using Ubuntu 16.04.

I can get a zip file from [Blender.org](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/), but I'm managing a lab full of computers with puppet and I've got mass install of deb files figured out, but not from zip...

Is there a Blender 2.78c deb file somewhere for Xenial or Debian Stretch?

Edit, the closest I've found is 2.78a: https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/blender_2.78.a+dfsg0-4_amd64.deb.html

Comment: If i can understand you clearly you want to install on your computer **Blender 2.78c ?**

Comment: Yes, but not from the zip file (because I don't know how to install from zips on a lab using puppet)

Comment: Do you use Software-center Application your computer  ?

Comment: If you use it just search for blender and you will find it

Comment: Or [Here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/blender/) is an internet url for downloading blender for ubuntu

Comment: @ShamsEl-Deen I did search, and can't find it, which is why I'm posting here. The software center offers 2.66a, not the version I am looking for here.

Comment: Did you opened the link i attached ?

Comment: Your link is to 2.66a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65438/discussion-between-shams-el-deen-and-43tesseracts).

Comment: Best place to find such things is usually google or any other search engine. Here is one result for example: https://debian.pkgs.org/sid/debian-main-amd64/blender_2.78.c+dfsg0-2+b1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: @LukeD this is for Debian Sid, not Stretch.  Won't that be a problem?

Comment: I don't have any available installation of Xenial or Stretch, just check it. It should be ok.

Comment: on that ppa it seems there is a 2.78c version deb? https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender/+files/blender_2.78c~1487946787-0thomas~yakkety1_amd64.deb or maybe I missed some point... ok it's named as yakkety but since 2.78a it should not be that different...

Comment: @LukeD I get this error when trying to install the Debian Sid pkg: `Error: Dependancy is not satisfiable: blender-data(=2.78.c+dfsg0-2)`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem last night. Fortunately, I found a copy of the original 2.78c package in my apt cache. Here is my solution:

- purge any existing blender installation (via apt-get) `sudo apt-get purge blender`
- add the [ppa Thomas Schiex](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender;
  sudo apt-get update;` (Do not install blender from there directly. It would install 2.79 again, which we do not want here!)
- download the 2.78c version of blender manually from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4SAG_u19QW3RnhGYk5tU3kxekE (I would prefer a more official link to a working package here, but I found non.)
- install the package via gdebi (assuming you downloaded to `/home/$USER/Downloads`): `sudo gdebi /home/$USER/Downloads/blender_2.78c~1487946787-0thomas~xenial1_amd64.deb` (dependencies are resolved from ppa Thomas Schiex)
- Finished! Enjoy your 2.78c version of blender again.
- to prevent from automatic updates, set the package to be unmodifiable: `sudo apt-mark hold blender`